# What is the difference between var and string in C#?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between `var` and `string` in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the point of the var keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209199/whats-the-point-of-the-var-keyword) or even [Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp) (downvote because you question could be answered easily with the help of google or msdn)

Comment: I don't why some guys Vote down this Question. I know its silly question but working with doubts will never improve your coding. So that's why I was asking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The keyword `var` is used for declaration of implicit types. If you are using a named type for the variable, there is no other difference than readability (and opinions differ on which is better). Example:

```
var s = "asdf";
```

gives exactly the same result as:

```
string s = "asdf";
```

However, if you have an unnamed type, you have to use `var` to declare a variable that has that type. Example:

```
var o = new { s = "asdf" };
```

There is no corresponding declaration using a named type, because the type of the object that is created doesn't have a name.

The `var` keyword is often used with LINQ and LINQ extension methods, when the result doesn't have a named type. Example:

```
var result = someList.Where(x => x.Age < 10).Select(x => new { name = x.Name });
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa ! Its mine answer.

Comment: ie nicely handle anonymous types, very nicely said :) +1

Answer (score 6):

`var` is an implicit type and `string` is an explicit type but these declarations are functionaly equivalent

```
var implicitString = "hello";
string explicitString = "hello";
```

Only variables that are declared at method scope can have an implicit type `var`. When used, compiler infers the type from the right side of the assignment.

Comment: Actually some time we store data source in var (like below scenario). So I am confused that it stores sequence of character or work as dataTable or ArrayList.                                                                                                                                                                                 var qurey= datasource();//order by page id
            if(qurey != null)
            {
                ddlpagenubers.DataSource = qurey;

Comment: @John: it stores whatever `datasource()` returns. Check method return type to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

First off, these are C# keywords, not ASP.NET.

`string` is a type - an explicit type that basically gets replaced by the compiler with `System.String`.

`var` is a keyword that stands in for a type - when the compiler can tell what the type of a variable should be (say from the return type of a function, or a literal). If you use a string, the compiler will make the same replacement as above.

Answer (score 3):

There is no legitimate comparison between var and string.

'var' is used for declaring implicit types be it an int , string , double , an object etc etc. It is useful when you don't exactly know the return type of a method Or you are not concerned with it at all.

'string' is a particular data type which can hold only string data and not of any type.

Also for a var the type must be defined at the time of declaration of var variable i.e at compile time only, otherwise the compiler will flag compile time error.
Hence while

```
string abc;
```

is possible but

```
var abc;
```

is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Tariq, It clears my doubt. And to all for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Var is used to declare Implicitly typed variable where the compiler identifies the type automatically. var can hold any type of data. String is an explicit declaration for holding string data only.

```
var i=5; 
var a="abcd"; 
var b= 5.5555; 
var c=new class(); 


String s = "ABCD";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual difference in VB.NET, there is another [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533166/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-v-as-string-and-dim-v-as-string) with more info