# Array data type

Tags: vb.net

Can somebody help me with arrays. in fact I don't understand the difference between these declarations:

```
Dim MyArray as integer()={5,3,2}
```

and

```
Dim MyArray() as integer={5,3,2}
```

and

```
Dim MyArray as array={5,3,2}
```

I have written a large code some variables are defined by the third approach. Now I need to change the size of my array and add new elements one by one to my array, but

```
array.resize(MyArray,newsize)
```

just works on arrays defined by the first and second method.
How I can change the size of array defined by the third method. How can I add elements to this type of array one by one?

Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Dim v As String() and Dim v() As String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533166/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-v-as-string-and-dim-v-as-string)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about resizing arrays, you should consider using the `List(Of T)` data structure, which will automatically grow to the size of the amount of objects you want to store, like this:

```
Dim MyListOfIntegers As New List(Of Integer)()
```

Now you can add to the list of integers, like this:

```
MyListOfIntegers.Add(5)
MyListOfIntegers.Add(3)
MyListOfIntegers.Add(2)
```