# arrayVariable() As Object vs. arrayVariable As Object() – not the same in Property declaration?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, declaration

Until today, I thought that the following two notations are the same (edit: `Dim` was replaced by `Property`)

```
Property arrayVariable() As Object 
Property arrayVariable As Object()
```

Today I found that former one throws error *`Option Strict On disallows late binding.`* while the latter compiles OK in expression `dictionary1.TryGetValue(CStr(arrayVariable(0)), result)`.

**Please what is the difference between them?**

I would always use the second notation if it also allowed to specify the array dimensions. It doesn't, so I stuck with the first form (less clean one, because part of type specification - parenthesis - are before `As`) in order to be consistent across declarations. And now I see that even the first one isn't universal...

*It really looks like a weak point of Visual Basic that two forms exist for one thing and their usage is not straightforward but has catches like this.*

Full source code reproducing the issue:

```
Public Class Class1
    Dim _A1() As Object
    Dim _A2() As Object

    ReadOnly Property A1() As Object ' 1st form of declaration
        Get
            Return _A1
        End Get
    End Property

    ReadOnly Property A2 As Object() ' 2nd form of declaration
        Get
            Return _A2
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim c1 As New Class1
    Dim d1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim value As String = ""
    d1.TryGetValue(CStr(c1.A1(0)), value)  '<- Option Strict On disallows late binding.
    d1.TryGetValue(CStr(c1.A2(0)), value)  '<- No error here.
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please provide the complete block of code that contains the `dictionary1.TryGetValue(CStr(arrayVariable(0)), result)` code?

Comment: Question already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533166/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-v-as-string-and-dim-v-as-string

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo - looks I have discovered the case NOT covered by answers in question you linked :) Try the code yourself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that they are Properties so the `()` is ignored as an Array specifier and thinks of it as an empty parameter collection. Look at how the compiler see them - even the compiler thinks you had an Object and not a `Object()` and so in your example the `A1(0)` is an index of an object which is not defined so it thinks you have done some late binding and made it accept an array.

If you are not using a Property and an Object type either declaration is valid.

```
Dim data() As String
```

Same as

```
Dim data As String()
```

If you highlight either variable the intellisence shows you:

```
 Dim data() As String
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the minimum amount of code required to replicate your issue:

```
Dim y As Object
Dim x = y(0)
```

This has nothing to do with the declaration of arrays. You're just trying to convert an `Object` to an array which option strict doesn't allow.

Comment: you made the merit obvious, but the case is not so obvious at property declaration where syntactically a variable definition is seen although function header notation has obviously priority in interpretation of declaration as @OneFineDay noted.

Answer (score 0):

#### Additional notes:

(not sure why this has been downvoted)

Changing `Object` to `Integer` reveals the first form mentioned in question is not taken as declaration.

```
Public Class Class1
    Dim _A1 As Integer()
    Dim _A2 As Integer()

    ReadOnly Property A1() As Integer
        Get
            Return _A1 
          ' error at above line: Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot
          ' be converted to 'Integer'.
        End Get
    End Property
    ReadOnly Property A2 As Integer()
        Get
            Return _A2
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Proper way is

```
    ReadOnly Property A1() As Integer()
```

Comment: When the declaration is for a property, fields can be done either way.

Comment: @OneFineDay - please could you show what do you mean by "either way"? I'm not sure.

Comment: @OneFineDay - OK, I understand that for `Dim` both forms of declaration have the same meaning, but this is NOT true for `Property`. I'm not speaking about its backing store, but about property declaration itself, which can be also written without its backing store as `Property A1() As Integer`. Then as you correctly noted, `Property A1() As Integer` and `Property A1 As Integer()` aren't the same. For *Object* type, it won't be reported until such a property is used (tricky!), but for other types, problem is reported immediately. I do not understand downvoting of my answer explaining this.

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted you. Sure it seems tricky, the difference is with an Object and other DataTypes and how properties are declared - as I stated in my answer.