# In VB.NET where do you put the brackets when defining an array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, convention

this is my first question here on SO.  I have been a long time reader, you all do great stuff!

What is the difference between:

```
Dim myArray() as Type
```

and;

```
Dim myArray as Type()
```

I have seen many examples that use these different notations and when I look at MSDN documentation it is always shown as the first example.

Is this just a user preference? Is there some underlying operation happening that I am not aware? Visual studio seems to treat them separately, but i read them as being "[variable] array of type" and "[variable] of type array".  The second being a bit confusing.

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate question, and thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Does the second example even compile?  The equivalent wouldn't compile in C#, but VB.NET tends to be a bit looser on some things.

Comment: Also a duplicate of: [What is the difference between Dim v As String() and Dim v() As String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533166/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-v-as-string-and-dim-v-as-string)

Comment: See also [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Comment: Yes @Tim, it does. :)